# Update mysql data or record using VB.net with datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Hi guys I need help in updating the data on my datagridview. The Scenario is when I click the Search it will query the appropriate data and display that I want to the datagridview. Then I want to update if their any changes or deleted data from datagridview then also update to my mysql table for new data or record whenever I click the Update Button and it will prompts a messagebox if their is a successfully changes to my data and prompts if their is no changes to my data. I really need help the codes for update button.
Here is my code to the search button to the datagridview:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim sql As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable

 Private Sub cmdSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click
        con.ConnectionString = ("server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=12345;database=dbsis3bkenth;")

Try
            conn.Open()

        sql = "SELECT LName,FName,MI FROM tblsisterbrother where IDNoBrodSis = '" & cbIDNo.Text & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()

        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Record Found.!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Record Unfound.!")
        End If
        dr.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error in searching to database:error is:" & ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    dr.Close()
    RemoveHandler DataGridView1.CellValidating, AddressOf DataGridView1_CellValidating
    Dim DataAdapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
    DataAdapter1.SelectCommand = cmd
    DataAdapter1.Fill(ds, "tblsisterbrother")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "tblsisterbrother"
    conn.Dispose()
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Then I want a code for the update, it will be place here:

```
 Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdUpdate.Click
```

I want this kind of messagebox appears if the rows affected, this code does not run to what I want, just for reference on how to update. Please help me :)

```
If DataGridView1.DataSource.GetChanges() Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("The table contains no changes to save.")
        Else
            Dim rowsAffected As Integer = da.Update(dt)
            If rowsAffected = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("No rows were affected by the save operation.")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(rowsAffected & " rows were affected by the save operation.")
            End If
        End If
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that you use a different DataAdapter when you fill the grid from the one that you want to use when you update the database.

You could simply change the code that fills the grid and make use of the global dataadapter declared in the class

```
' Dim DataAdapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter'
da.SelectCommand = cmd
da.Fill(ds, "tblsisterbrother")
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
.....
```

Now when you call the Update method you are using the same adapter, just give it a littel help in building the required update/insert and delete command using a MySqlCommandBuilder

```
DataGridView1.EndEdit()
Dim dt As DataTable
dt = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
If dt.GetChanges() Is Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show("The table contains no changes to save.")
Else
    Dim builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
    Dim rowsAffected As Integer = da.Update(dt)
    If rowsAffected = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No rows were affected by the save operation.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(rowsAffected & " rows were affected by the save operation.")
    End If
End If
```

Comment: There is an error sir to this line:
 If dt.GetChanges() Is Nothing Then

.it says NullReferenceException was unhandled

Comment: I already use your code for update sir by the way. but it really show me that error. Please Help me sir. Maybe this code in my Private Form1_Load causes this error, this is the code:  `DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False`

Comment: Uhm probably is because you set the datasource to a dataset instead of a datatable. That could be fixed changing the initial setting to ds.Tables(0) instead

Comment: Another Problem sir, now that I change the setting and follow you, another error occur to this line when I search: `DatagridView1.DataMember = "tblsisterbrother"` and I try to remove this and run the search again it works and display the data to the datagridview but when change the data to datagrid and update it prompts me the msgbox: `The table contains no changes to save` what will I do sir?

Comment: Did you call somewhere AcceptChanges on the table or DataSource?

Comment: No sir. How could I fix this? is this `DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False` causes my rows to error and I cannot update with it?

Comment: I don't think that AutogenerateColumns has something to play in this situation. Instead, before the check for changes add a line with _DataGridView1.EndEdit()_ This will commit any pending changes to the underlying datasource and it is probably needed if you have the current cell in edit mode when you press the update button

Comment: If this also doesn't work, I can only recommend to post a new question with your updated code and ask if someone else has a new view on the situation. Sorry but it is past midnight here I am going to sleep a bit now. Goodnight.

Comment: I did it your suggestion sir but the same msgbox appears `The table contains no changes to save` .

Comment: hehe,, Ok2 sir.. thank you for your help by the way :)